# Magento 2 Add to cart Flow

Tags: magento2, addtocart

Explain the add to cart flow in magento 2. I need which files call after we click add to cart button in magento 2. Please help me

Answer (score 3):

When someone hit 'Add to Cart' button. It's called **execute** method of following class:

```
Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php
```

When someone update item from shopping cart page. It's called **execute** method of following class:

```
Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/UpdatePost.php
```

When someone delete item. It's called **execute** method of following class:

```
Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Delete.php
```

Comment: Hey Sohel what about configurable product for add to cart.